# How to customize itemize item symbol based on beamer class, in template

Tags: beamer, itemize

I am designing a latex template for making presentation slides, and I use `beamer` class for it.

I want to use:

1. '>' sign as item symbol (for all layers of itemize: item, subitem, subsubitem)
2. '>' sign are all in color like light blue, which is specified by RGB values: (0, 100, 240)
3. The size of subitem sign is a bit smaller than the size of item sign.

See the following figure.

[image]

I want to make the template a bit well organized so I prefer to define it in 'beamerinnerthemesmycompany.sty' file.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0, 100, 240}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=myblue}

\setbeamerfont{itemize item}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize subitem}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize subsubitem}{size=\tiny}

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{mytheme}{%
    \usebeamerfont*{itemize item}$>$
}

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subitem}{mytheme}{%
    \usebeamerfont*{itemize subitem}$>$
}

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subsubitem}{mytheme}{%
    \usebeamerfont*{itemize subsubitem}$>$
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item test
        \begin{itemize}
            \item test
            \begin{itemize}
                \item test
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. It works well. However, do you have any suggestion on how to make the '>' sign narrower, just like the way I show in my picture?

Comment: @aura Either find a font with a narrower > or draw it in `tikz` or similar. Or use `\resizebox` to deform the symbol - however this might look result in strange line widths - use at your own risk.